# Query regarding row cache in DataStax/Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I created a CF with caching='ROWS_ONLY' and loaded it with some data. I then configured/enabled row caching by editing the cassandra.yaml file. With tracing on, I ran a select query and it displayed row cache miss (expected) and the query took 10 seconds. I ran the query again and this time it showed row cache hit (again expected) but the time take to run the query was again 10 seconds. Is this normal? I was expecting that the second time the query ran, it should have taken less than 10 sec. Am I missing something here? Are there any other parameters to check/configure to achieve better read performance with row cache enabled?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: What kind of query are you running that takes 10 seconds?

Comment: It's a select * from <cf> with the primary key specified. It returns 5800 rows and I am writing the output to an ASCII file via a shell script.

Comment: The row cache is probably not a great fit for this. See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/row-caching-in-cassandra-2-1

Comment: Are you using one of the DataStax drivers with automatic paging? What's your use case for pulling 5k rows?

Comment: The query returning 5800 rows was just an example. I could have a query return 600 rows in x seconds and if I run the same query immediately, it still takes x seconds in spite of a row cache hit. My expectation is that when the query is run the second time it should take less than x seconds.

Comment: I am not using DataStax drivers with automatic paging.

Comment: What programming language / driver,?

Comment: Using cqlsh. The question is - using cqlsh, with row cache enabled, and row cache hit, can I even expect a time difference in running same query twice. If this is the use case, how can I achieve it?